# Package arules in R: getting rules with only one item in the left-hand side

Tags: r, arules

I am using the package arules in R to generate association rules.  I would like
to restrict the rules so that in the left-hand side there's only one
particular element, let's call it "potatoe".

If I do this:

```
rules <- apriori(dtm.mat, parameter = list(sup = 0.4, conf =
0.9,target="rules"), appearance = list(lhs = c("potatoe")))
```

I get "potatoe" on the lhs, but also all other kinds of things. How can I
force that the rules contain only one element? The parameter maxlen don't do
what I want, because, as far as I can see, I cannot specify the maxlen to
apply to the elements on the left.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you've generated the rules ("rules", in your question), here is how to subset it. Basically, you have to coerce the data into a data frame and then subset it.

```
#Here are the original rules generated with some data I created
# categories are "G", "T", "D", and "potatoe"

> inspect(rules);
lhs        rhs      support    confidencelift
1  {}  => {T}       0.3333333  0.3333333 1.0000000
2  {}  => {G}       0.5000000  0.5000000 1.0000000
3  {}  => {potatoe} 0.5000000  0.5000000 1.0000000
4  {}  => {D}       0.5000000  0.5000000 1.0000000
5  {T} => {G}       0.1666667  0.5000000 1.0000000
6  {G} => {T}       0.1666667  0.3333333 1.0000000
7  {T} => {D}       0.1666667  0.5000000 1.0000000
8  {D} => {T}       0.1666667  0.3333333 1.0000000
9  {G} => {potatoe} 0.1666667  0.3333333 0.6666667
10 {potatoe} => {G} 0.1666667  0.3333333 0.6666667
11 {potatoe} => {D} 0.3333333  0.6666667 1.3333333
12 {D} => {potatoe} 0.3333333  0.6666667 1.3333333

#Coerce into data frame
as(rules, "data.frame");

#Restrict LHS to only certain value (here, "potatoe")
rules_subset <- subset(rules, (lhs %in% c("potatoe")));

#Check to see subset rules
inspect(rules_subset);
lhs            rhs support    confidencelift
1 {potatoe} => {G} 0.1666667  0.3333333 0.6666667
2 {potatoe} => {D} 0.3333333  0.6666667 1.3333333
```

This method also allows for arbitrarily many LHS values, not just one. Much easier than my previously proposed answer.

Comment: What is this line for?    as(rules, "data.frame");

Answer (score 4):

Mate, you just have to add `default="rhs"` in the appearance parameter list, and you're done.

```
rules <- apriori(dtm.mat, parameter = list(sup = 0.4, conf =
0.9,target="rules"), appearance = list(lhs = c("potatoe"), default="rhs"))
```

The `lhs=c("potatoe")` parameter tells the algorithm that the LHS should only contain "potatoe", and the `default="rhs"` parameter tells the algorithm that the RHS should be the default one (i.e. no constraints are to be applied there).

Answer (score 0):

The subset() function provides a method to search for subsets of transactions, items, or rules.

```
potatoerules <- subset(rules , items %in% "potatoe")
```

Answer (score -6):

Here is one method:

> 1. Generate list of rules using inspect().
> 2. Copy all rules into text editor.
> 3. Save as .txt file.
> 4. Open in excel as fixed-width delimited file.
> 5. Filter the LHS to only include "potatoe" [sic].

There may be an easier way, but at least you won't have to manually search for "potatoe" [sic] on the left-hand side.